# Encode and Decode String using Base32

Tags: java, android, string, base32

I want to use Base32 for encoding and decoding for a string.
But I am getting error while am using **Apache Commons Codec 1.11**

I have used this answer but not work for me ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21515479/encode-string-to-base32-string-in-java))
([link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47011179/more-than-one-file-was-found-with-os-independent-path-org-apache-http-client-ve)).

This is the **error** [Screenshot](http://prntscr.com/l0q0pp) which is I am facing...

Thanks...!!!

**EDIT :-**

[Check this Screen shot](http://prntscr.com/l0qard)

jar file downloaded from here : [click me](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/download_codec.cgi)

Comment: remove all files from libs except `commons-codec-1.11.jar`

Comment: I did but after that m getting this error :- Unable to delete file: C:\Users\GLB-BAN-414\AndroidStudioProjects\Gramboard\app\build\intermediates\transforms\mergeJavaRes\debug\0.jar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of this options should help you:

**Option 1**: Add this to your build.gradle:

```
android {
    // Your main config here...
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'org/apache/commons/codec/language/bm/gen_approx_hungarian.txt'
    }
}
```

Make sure, that I copied conflicting file name correctly from your screenshot.

**Option 2:** Remove test libraries from dependencies list:
commons-codec-1.11-tests.jar
commons-codec-1.11-test-sources.jar

Comment: I did but after that m getting this error :- Unable to delete file: C:\Users\GLB-BAN-414\AndroidStudioProjects\Gramboard\app\build\intermediates\transforms\mergeJavaRes\debug\0.jar

Comment: Try to make clean build.

Comment: I have removed all libraries except this commons-codec-1.11.jar

Comment: Delete folder by yourself: C:\Users\GLB-BAN-414\AndroidStudioProjects\Gramboard\app\build\

Comment: @AndreiVinogradov I have edited my question check this screenshot I have tried to delete as manually

Comment: Reboot and than delete. Something in system is using that file.

Comment: @AndreiVinogradov oky after doing this I will let you know